# php - Iterate and Skip All Values Containing The Previous Values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, skip

I want to check two arrays that contain similar elements. If the element in the second array containing the same element inside the first array, then save it and ignore everything after it that contain that element. And if any element in the second array is not an element of the first array and not contain any element in the first array, then save it too.

It basically is like this:

```
$array_1 = Array(

[0] => car,
[1] => bike,
[2] => plane,
[3] => ship

);


$array2 = Array(

[0] => tiger_claws,
[1] => bike,
[2] => bike_1,
[3] => bike_30,
[4] => bike_clone,
[5] => bike_sold,
[6] => plane,
[7] => plane_3a,
[8] => plane_fly

);
```

From the array examples above, I want to take `tiger_claws` `bike` and `plane` into new separated array that will be named `$new_array`. The actual data I processed is dynamic, so I need a dynamic approach too.

Here is my try to achieve it:

```
    $count = count($array2);    
    $new_array = array();

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {

      foreach($array_1 as $arr){

               if ($array2[$i] == $arr) {

                  $new_array[] = $arr;

                  if (strpos($array2[$i], $arr)){
                     continue;
                  }                     

               } elseif (strpos($array2[$i], $arr) === false){

                  $new_array[] = $arr;

           }

         }

     }
```

How do I catches the `tiger_claws`, `bike` and `plane` only and then put them into `$new_array` and leave everything else?

**EDIT:**
The `$array2` may sometimes contain one or more elements that have underscore and that element not containing any string/ element in `$array_1`.

This thing is very complicated for me. Hope somebody would like to give the correct logic!

Best Regards

Comment: I'm not sure how `$array_1` is used at all here, because both "tiger_claws" and "bike" should be in the new array but only the latter is inside array_1.

Comment: `$array_1` is used for filtering the `$array2`'s elements. If there are any element in `$array2` that is exactly matched any element in `$array_1`, or if that element is not contain any element in the `$array_1`, then save it into `$new_array`. But if any `array2`'s element is not exactly matched any element in `$array_1` but it's contain it and there is any element of `$array_1` in `$array2` that is exactly matched with the element of `$array_1` contained in that `$array2`'s element, then skip it (eg.: if there is `bike` and `bike_1`, then save `bike` and ignore `bike_1`).

Comment: Sorry, tried to answer your question, but it's hopelessly complicated. Perhaps you should give a better (real world) example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying... :) I also feel that it's complicated. What I actually want to do is processing a tree menu of wordpress post types, containing all of its taxonomies, taxonomy items, single posts and authors names. I think it's far more complicated if I use it as example, so I minified it to the example abpve...!

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array();
foreach ($array2 as $string) {
    if (!in_array($string, $array1) && 
        !in_array($string, $new_array) && 
        !strpos($string, '_')) {
        $new_array[] = $string;
    }
}
```

This code loops through `$array2` and checks:

- if the current array value is in `$array1` (if so, ignore it)
- if the current array value is already in `$new_array` (if so, ignore it)
- if the underscore '`_`' is *not* present in the current array

If so, it is added to `$new_array`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just edited the question a bit. I want also save any element in `array2` that is contained in `array_1`. Your code ignores everything that is contained in `array_1`. And `$new_array` is a blank array that will be filled by array's element filtered with the iteration, so it don't need to check what is inside it! The `$array2` may containing one or more elements that have underscore and that element will not containing any string/ element in `$array_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found. Hope someone can benefit from this answer! Please suggest me the more elegant solution if you have it.

**First**, we check if there are any element of `$array_1` that is contained in `$array2` and collect them to a new array if there is matched element:

```
$check = array();

foreach(array2 as $arr){

  foreach($array_1 as $arr1){

     if($arr == $arr1) {
        $check[] = $arr;
     }    

  }

}
```

**Next**, do the filtering with the new array created above and save the elements we want into `$new_array`

```
$new_array = array();

foreach(array2 as $arr){

  foreach($check as $chk){

     if($arr == $chk || strpos($arr, $chk) === false) {
        $new_array[] = $arr;
     }    

  }

}
```

**Now**, the `$new_array` elements will be:

```
tiger_claws,
bike,
plane
```

About `strpos`. According to my test and the reference [here](http://php.net//manual/en/function.strpos.php), `!strpos($var1, $var2)` is not the correct opposite of `strpos($var1, $var2)`. This is an example of the correct way to test if `strpos` is false:

```
    if(strpos($var1, $var2) === false) {
      // do your stuff
    }
```